# pygtk: How to change menu text size?

Tags: menu, pygtk, font-size

I'm trying to use PyGTK 2 in a touch environment, and the items in menus (popups) are too small. I found `gtk.settings_get_for_screen` and `gtk.settings_get_default`, and the `gtk-font-name` property, but changing that on either the default or the screen-specific settings didn't change the appearance of any of my text. Is there a style associated with menu items that I can change? Or is there some way of getting at the underlying text objects and using `modify_font(pango.FontDescription('...'))` on them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use gtk.MenuItem, then you can apply modify_font (pango.FontDescription ('...')) for the get_child method.

For example:

```
item = gtk.MenuItem("item")
child = item.get_child()
child.modify_font(pango.FontDescription("sans 20"))
```